# Multiple placeholders in localization in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, localization, localizedstringkey

I need to have multiple placeholders in the localization text, but having a hard time differentiating them. For example:

```
English:
"some_currency %@ %@" = "%@ %@"; // 1233454.34 USD

Arabic:
"some_currency %@ %@" = "%@ %@"; // USD ١٢٣٣٤٥٤.٣٤

...

let balance = CurrencyFormatter.string(1233454.34)
let currency = "USD"
LocalizedStringKey("some_currency \(balance) \(currency)")
```

How can I specify which placeholders go where since I need to swap them?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65187817/12299030?

Comment: Unfortuntately no, I need some kind of handle on which interpolation placeholder is which